# Deploying Qt Application on Android is really slow?

Tags: android, qt

As you may know there are three ways to deploy a Qt application on Android :

1. **Use Ministro service to install Qt**
2. **Deploy local Qt libraries to temporary directory**
3. **Bundle Qt libraries in APK**

The first method takes about 30 seconds and it also needs to install an extra apk . **Ministro**.
The second takes about 1 minute for me ! And anytime I try to run the program Qt creator pushes Qt libraries to the device.
The third one makes the .apk file really big and again takes about 1 minute for me.
I think with this situation that's not reasonable to develop Android application using Qt. Is there a way to make the deploying process faster?

Comment: "that's not reasonable to develop Android application using Qt" It's still just a preview of technology, not a final product.

Comment: That is already pretty decent for a technology preview though. Do realise that it will at the very best be around 10-15 seconds build time (with the average pc and a better qt build). Also why do you think it isn't reasonable (just curious here) do other programs do this faster with the NDK?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman I don't think it's pretty enough, tried to deploy simple "hello world" and it crashed everytime ;) but I'll give it a try once more time.

Comment: @ariwez Taking a day to set it up seems to be everyone's problem. When you do get it configured I get build times that are comparable to mosync etc.

Comment: I WISH we had ONLY troubles like you are having; take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358144/qt-creator-android-unbearable-instability-of-deployment-debugging-process it's not a single setup. it takes long and then it fails. feels like operating a 'super-computer' from 70s.. or makes feel deploying an app to Android like sending a probe to Mars.

Comment: @Vega4 I stopped using Qt for Android since that days -_- because of its shortcomings.

Answer (score 2):

Almost a full year since the OP and things have not changed at all. Deployment of a 7 MB APK takes over minute and a half for a project that compiles in 5 seconds. The reason I am answering is not that the problem got resolved, but to offer an alternative solution.

I've implemented a "workaround" consisting of two applications that work in tandem - one on the PC and one on the device - I created this mostly to compile files remotely, but it turned out to be a much faster alternative for deployment as well. On the host create an application that launches compilation in a separate process, when done copy the product file over network to the device to deploy. Besides remote compilation this reduced the time to deploy to like 10 seconds, I can live with that.

Comment: 4.5 years later :), its still very slow for me. is that to say that I should compile on QT Creator,  and then copy the apk? have to say compilation is super slow too

Comment: Compilation for me for an empty is about 20 sec, not so much compilation than building the APK, maybe your pc is slow? Keep in mind the first time you try it, it will download a bunch of stuff, but afterwards it will be faster as it will no longer have to download the tools. The AMR emulator is still slow buggy and crashy, but 4.5 years later there are now also x86 emulator images, which run pretty well.

Comment: thanks! the pc is an i5, pretty good usually...  the process that takes ages is C:\Qt\Qt5.11.2\5.11.2\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe. how can i get and use  x86 emulator images? that could be very useful

Comment: Install an image for your android API through the android sdk manager and set up an emulator that uses it in creator. Keep in mind you will have to build your app for android x86 in order for the emulator to be able to run it.

Comment: I seems like no one has reported the issue to Qt before, so I have. Please feel free to upvote the issue: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74830

Answer (score 0):

*(Not a complete and fully tested answer yet, but I'll update if I find out more …)*

### Option 1: Copy the changed libraries to a rooted device

A new build will most often result only in one changed file: your `libAppName.so`, the native library containing your application's code. At least in 2015, it was possible to simply copy over this library to the Android device, without having to re-build the APK package. This only works with rooted Android devices (note that all emulators are rooted by default).

Step by step, [according to this blog article](http://nootka-app.blogspot.com/2015/11/story-of-porting-complex-qt-application_18.html) and updated with the paths as I found them on my device:

1. Run the cross-compilation step on your build host system. So just `make` or the equivalent in Qt Creator.
2. Copy the resulting `libAppName.so` to the rooted Android device:

   ```
   adb push build/path/libAppName.so /data/app/com.example.appname/lib/arm
   ```
3. Restart the application on the Android device.

If that works, you might even be able to integrate it as a custom deployment step in Qt Creator.

I did not test this technique yet due to lack of a rooted device. But it should still work given that (1) rooted Android devices still allow to overwrite all files and (2) debug builds of APKs can still be installed without code signing, so overwriting a library in an APK without code signing should be possible.

### Option 2: Desktop targets as a workaround

I found out by chance that Qt's multi-platform character can be used to avoid the slow Android deployment 80% of the time. You just set up another compilation target; under Qt Creator you'd add a target under "Projects → Build & Run", using a kit for "Device Type: Desktop".

Now when you want to test anything that is not Android-specific, test instead in the Desktop version. Building and starting that will only take a few seconds.

This approach is further supported by using a framework for convergent application development so that the same user interface is usable both in the desktop and mobile versions. [KDE Kirigami](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kirigami) and [MauiKit](https://mauikit.org/) are two libraries for this purpose that build on Qt. Documentation for getting started is a bit scarce, but for Kirigami I wrote [an extensive README](https://github.com/fairdirect/foodrescue-app#readme) for the setup of an example application.